# how to style a tooltip of asp:image

Tags: c#, html

I'm planning to apply a css on ToolTip attribute of asp:Image but it's not working. This is what I've tried so far.

```
      <asp:Image ID="sampleimage" runat="server" 
      ImageUrl="~/Image/questionmark.png" ToolTip='<%# Eval("NAME") %>' 
      CssClass="tooltips" />

      ^ the text on tooltip shows but the css is not. It only has a white 
      background color.

      .tooltips
      {
      background-color: Green;
      width:150px;
      height:20px;
      }
```

This is from my stylesheet from other folders.

I'm totally new at using CSS. Any form of instructions will help. Thank you

Comment: try to read [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1198710.aspx?Giving+Styles+to+Tooltip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not style tooltips with CSS only, because they are rendered by the browser, not your web page.

But you can use a JS library to render custom tooltips (which allow custom styling). 
I like to use [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/).